# artifactoryPublish task is looking for default zip file of distribution plugin

Tags: build.gradle, artifactory, gradlew

I upgraded my enviornment from gradle 1.12 to gradle 2.10 & java7 to java8.After upgrading my environment all of sudden one task of my build.gradle is not working
artifactoryPublish.I am using distrobution plugin to create a custom zip files.Below is the error I am getting

- What went wrong:
  14:24:05  Execution failed for task ':artifactoryPublish'.
  14:24:05  > File 'F:\jenkins03\workspace\DataGenerator\build\distributions\DataGenerator-28_42_00_00.zip' does not exists, and need to be published!

I am not sure why it is trying to look for default zip files

Answer (score 0):

Include the distributions block in the gradle script where you have included the distribution plugin. Below is the sample.

```
distributions {
    main {
        baseName = archivesBaseName
        contents {
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```